# How to add values into Excel table by clicking a button?

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I need to fill catalog.

I want to make a input `Userform` for this, where by clicking a button `add new product` values in `Textboxes` will be inserted to specific column

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Sheet3.Cells.Rows.Insert
 Sheet3.Cells(25, 27).Value = TextBox1.Value



End Sub
```

Comment: Insert a blink row,change cell value to textbox.text

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: error  1004

i know that it can't work ...

Comment: Re tag edit, this was as per the wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info and various discussions on meta.

Comment: How come it doesn't apply to questions like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962021/programmatically-changing-the-recordsettype-in-ms-access-or-a-better-method/14967325#14967325

Comment: It does. Why would it not?

Comment: Fair enough. I was not aware of the VBA wiki update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Sheet3
        '~~> Insert row at the 25th row.
        .Rows(25).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        '~~> Add textbox value
        .Cells(25, 27).Value = TextBox1.Value
    End With
End Sub
```