# Programmatically changing the RecordsetType in ms access or a better method

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

In ms access I have a form which also has a sub-form. I wanted to programmatically change the RecordsetType in the main-form to snapshot when the sub-table/sub-form has associated records in the one-to-many relationship. I wrote some vba code to do this but I was experiencing some very odd behaviour.

I then discovered that it was because when I change the RecordsetType, the form refreshes and navigates back to the first record. That then causes the On Current event and associated code to fire in both the sub-form and main-form twice. I was thinking of using DoCmd.SearchForRecord to navigate back to the original record but quickly realized that it wouldn't work because the the WHERE condition in the DoCmd.SearchForRecord gets overridden when the events fire the second time around. It all seemed so inefficient any way.

Are there any other methods to do what I am trying to do? I don't really want to set the controls in the form to 'Disabled'.

Comment: Why do you not wish to set allowedits property for the form? It is quite simple.

Comment: Yea, that is a pretty simple solution. I have been doing VBA programming for literally three weeks. Although the Recordset Type and Allow Edits are on the same tab in the property sheet I didn't even see that it was there. And the embarrassing part is that I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to get this to work. Thank you!

Comment: It is a really problem trying to see those things, there are so many dratted properties :)

Comment: The On Current event in the sub-form still runs twice though but I guess I could live with that.

Comment: You should not need to change at run time. You can disallow edits but allow additions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access has a selection of form properties that should suit: AllowEdits, AllowDeletions and AllowAdditions. These can be set separately or together. In this case, it seems that you need AllowAddition set to Yes and AllowEdits set to No.

[image: form properties]

Comment: I decided to programmatically change the Allow Edits property when necessary (I don't really need it for all records anyway). I don't know why but I realized that when I change Allow Edits to No in the main form then I can also not edit or add new records to my sub form but when I do it programmatically it works just fine and I am able to modify the sub form. I have tested this several times and my code is not very complicated at all. Also, the On Current event does not fire twice as previously mentioned.